# Copy and unzip archive as a part of a deployment process of a web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-files

I am developing a web application relying on SQLite database. My db file is supposed to be kept in App_Data directory. The size of the file is about 6 GB. It is not included in the project or the git repo.
Deployment process should include copying a zip archive (~1 GB) with the database from azure file storage and unzipping it. How could it be done?

Answer (score 1):

> How could it be done?

Based on my experience, you could use the [custom deployment script](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) to add your logic during deployment.

**Note**: As the file is about 6G, the [service plan tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/) B+ is required.

[image]